# How to handle missing values in R by replacing it with mean?

Tags: r

I have a data frame which looks like this

```
row1 key1 10 
row2 key1 12
row3 key1 NA
row4 key2 2
row5 key2 3
row6 key2 NA
...
```

Now i want to replace all NAs with mean values for each key. eg. 1st NA should be replaced by mean of 10, 12 and 2nd by mean of 2, 3

One crude solution is to get all keys, iterate over them, filter data frame for that specific key and then replace NAs with mean. Any other better solution ?

Comment: _get all keys, iterate over them, filter data frame_ That doesn't sound crude to me.

Comment: You are aware that imputation using the mean can be problematic? There may be [better alternatives](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/104743/when-is-it-a-good-idea-to-just-use-the-average-for-imputation) for your use case.

Comment: downvoters, care to explain why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There will be tons of ways to do this. The library `zoo` has a built in function `na.aggregate` which does precisely what you want.

```
library(zoo)
d <- data.frame(key = rep(c("key1", "key2"), each = 3), 
    value = c(10, 12, NA, 2, 3, NA))  
with(d, na.aggregate(value, by = key))
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is your data set

```
temp <- read.table(text = "row1 key1 10 
row2 key1 12
row3 key1 NA
row4 key2 2
row5 key2 3
row6 key2 NA", header = F)

library(data.table)
setDT(temp)[, V3 := as.numeric(V3)]
temp[, V3 := lapply(.SD, function(x) ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = T), V3)), .SDcols = "V3",  by = V2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
 dat <- read.table(text="row1 key1 10 
 row2 key1 12
 row3 key1 NA
 row4 key2 2
 row5 key2 3
 row6 key2 NA
 row7 key2 NA",sep="",header=F,stringsAsFactors=F)

 repl <- with(dat, table(is.na(V3),V2)[2,]) #to get the number of missing values per group
 dat1 <- dat
 indx <- is.na(dat$V3) #create a index of position of missing values
 dat$V3[indx] <- rep(with(dat, by(V3, V2, FUN=mean, na.rm=T)), repl) #replicate by `repl` in cases of multiple NAs per group
```

Or use `ave`

```
 dat1$V3[indx] <- with(dat1, ave(V3, V2, FUN=function(x) mean(x, na.rm=T)))[indx]
identical(dat1, dat)
#[1] TRUE

 dat1$V3
# [1] 10.0 12.0 11.0  2.0  3.0  2.5  2.5
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick, using your data:

```
 d <- data.frame(id = rep(c("key1", "key2"), each = 3), x = c(10, 12, NA, 2, 3, NA))  
 library(plyr)
 d2 <- ddply(d, .(id), transform, x=ifelse(is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm=T), x) )
```

Here, we split the dataframe by your `key` and transform `x` depending on whether or not it is `NA`. The result is

```
     id    x
 1 key1 10.0
 2 key1 12.0
 3 key1 11.0
 4 key2  2.0
 5 key2  3.0
 6 key2  2.5
```